# Single word for a person of few words

Tags: single-word-requests, metaphors

What is the single word for a person who expresses every emotion with a few or single word.

Comment: [taciturn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/taciturn)

Comment: **The** single word? As well as @F's *taciturn* you could consider [*laconic*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/laconic).